# Symfony Doctrine Join and In query

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to transform a SQL query into DQL and DQL delivers strange behavior.

I have this SQL

```
SELECT b_t.id
Inner Join tag_to_entry AS b_te ON b_t.id = b_te.tag_id
WHERE b_te.entry_id IN (
    SELECT a_te.entry_id
    FROM entry AS a_e
    Inner Join tag_to_entry AS a_te ON a_e.id = a_te.entry_id
    Inner Join tag AS a_t ON a_t.id = a_te.tag_id
    WHERE a_t.id = 9
)
AND b_te.tag_id != 9
GROUP BY b_t.id
HAVING COUNT(b_te.tag_id) > 2
```

And this is my repository method: (this is what I tried)

```
public function findRelatedTagsByTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $in = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Entry')
        ->createQueryBuilder('a_e')
        ->where(':tag MEMBER OF a_e.tags');

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("b_t");
    $qb->innerJoin('b_t.entries', 'b_te')
        ->where($qb->expr()->in('b_te', $in->getDQL()))
        // ->andWhere(':tag NOT MEMBER OF b_te.tags')
        // ->groupBy('b_t.id')
        // ->having('COUNT(b_te.tags) > 2')
        ->setParameters(array('tag' => $tag)); // Tag with ID: 9
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

If I call `findRelatedTagsByTag()` with all arguments commented out (like above) I get 9 records (without any duplicates). If I do the same with the SQL (also without the arguments) it returns 34 records (with duplicates).

If I comment `->groupBy('b_t.id')` back in it returns 9 records, too. In the SQL only 9. The same 9 records as in the repository method.

And If I comment `->andWhere(':tag NOT MEMBER OF b_te.tags')` back in it returns 0 records. And in my SQL 8 records, which is correct.

The `->having('COUNT(b_te.tags) > 2')` commented in throws an exception:

> Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected

---

I tested both subqueries and they return the same, so there is no mistake. I suspect DQL group by to early and without my statement commented in and this occurs this strange behavior. I hope somebody could explain this and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 6 hours of work I finally solved it:

```
$qb ->innerJoin('b_t.entries', 'b_te')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('b_te', $in->getDQL()))
    ->andWhere('b_t.id != :id')
    ->groupBy('b_t.id')
    ->having('COUNT(b_t.id) > 2')
    ->setParameters(array('tag' => $tag, 'id' => $tag->getId()));
```

The `->andWhere` does not need the `MEMBER OF` and I had to work with IDs.

The `->having` does not use the relation table. Instead it has to use the repository entity.